# Creating a very basic messaging schema in SQL

Tags: sql, message

Here's what I have:

```
create table Recipiente
(
RecipienteId int primary key identity(1,1),
MensajeId int foreign key references Mensaje(MensajeId)
)

create table Mensaje
(
MensajeId int primary key identity(1,1),
EnviadorId int foreign key references taJugador(jugCodigo), /* Sender */
Detalle nvarchar(1024) not null /* The actual message. */
)
```

I need to be able to message multiple people at the same time, so therein lies my problem. Note there is currently no relationship between the two tables, because I don't know how to proceed.

Any suggestions on completing this simple schema?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table to map the one-to-many relation that looks like this:

```
Table: Mensaje_Recipiente
Column 1: MensajeId
Column 2: RecipienteId
```

The primary key would be on both Ids. Let's say that message 5 is sent to users 4, 5 and 8, then you would add `(5, 4)`, `(5, 5)` and `(5, 8)` to your `Mensaje_Recipiente` table.

It allows you to find the messages a user has received (`SELECT MensajeId FROM mensaje_recipiente WHERE RecipienteId = ?`) or to find the recipients of a message (`SELECT RecipienteId FROM mensaje_recipiente WHERE MensajeId = ?`) pretty easily and you can get all the information you need by joining on their respective tables.

With this, you won't need `MensajeId` in the `Recipiente` table anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need a junction table.. Remove the MensajeId from the Recipiente table, and add a new table like this:

```
Recipiente_Mensaje
RecipienteId int foreign key references Recipiente(RecipienteId)
MensajeId int foreign key references Mensaje(MensajeId)
```

Both columns would be part of the primary key..

Answer (score 0):

Create tables like:

```
Messages
----------------------
Id (primary key)
SenderId
RecipientId
Message (you could replace this by an id and read it from an external table)

Peoples
----------------------
Id (primary key)
... some other data ...
```

Then for each message from a sender to a recipient add an entry to `Messages` referencing the persons from `Peoples` along with a message.